# Original styling does not extend to child elements after floating child sections

Tags: html, css

I originally had a  with one  in it and want to make it a div with two sections in it, one at 75% and another at 25%; like a sidebar. It is set up like this, with various  elements inside of the sections.

```
<div class="content">
    <section class="cs_one"> ... </section>
    <section class="cs_two"> ... </section>
</div>
```

Originally, the content section was styled with a background, border, and shadow, giving it this appearance.

[image: *Image of website with one column*]

```
.content {
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center content */
    padding-top: 150px; /* Move down from under fixed header */
    width: 1000px; 

    background-color: #D9C293;

    ... Border and box shadow styling omitted...
}
```

Then I added these lines of code to split the sections into two, giving it this undesired appearance. The red arrow shows where the previous content box (with the box shadow) ends after the image (which was before the two sections inside of the content div.

[image: Image of broken website with two columns]

```
.cs_one { width: 75%; float: left; }
.cs_two { width: 25%; float: right; }
```

**The content div's styling does not extend under the two sections. Why? How can I fix this.**

Comment: In your content class, try adding `overflow:hidden`

Comment: or `clear:both` after the content `.content::after{clear:both}`. Something like that, because you content div is not "growing" with its content.

Comment: @Timo002 Something I'm wondering from yours and other peoples answers is some of the theory behind this. When will I know to do this in other projects, where would it go then, etc?

Comment: The problem happens when a floated element is within a container box, that element does not automatically force the container’s height adjust to the floated element. When an element is floated, its parent no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow. http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html. it's just the way float works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an element is floated, its parent no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow.
You should use a `.clearfix`

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: But what element should have the "clearfix" class? And this seems like a very unintuitive and hacky way to do it. Is this common?

Comment: The `.clearfix`should be applied on the floated element.

Comment: On all floating elements?

Comment: Well, in your case on `.css_one` and `.css_two`, because as I wrote in my answer - this two elements are not children of the `.content` div if they are floated

Comment: So make your html like this `<section class="cs_two clearfix"> ... </section>`

Comment: I changed the code accordingly and it looks as it does in the second picture in the original post. My full code is here. https://gist.github.com/Elsealabs/13b43f50b893399c4e6a

Comment: hmm, are you able to share a link to your website?

Comment: @RamisWachtler The code in that gist is the only code that I have, but I could host the web pages on a server when I get to my computer in about an hour if that is needed.

Comment: I added it to the parent element instead of the child element and then it worked properly. I will mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the float.
Try adding a `<div class="clear-float"></div>` after `<section class="cs_two"> ... </section>`
and then add this inside your css

```
.clear-float {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: How will I know where to put this in future projects? Is there any explanation on how this works or why it goes in that place? Thank you.

Comment: When you float an element, the container (in your case `.content`) of the element does not "recognize it" as something that has a dimension. So, if you do not clear the float at the end (exactly before the closing tag of the container), the container height will end before the floated elements.

Comment: If you want to do something more accurate, you can take a look here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I understand. What is the difference between your clearfix method and the one in the other answer? It seems to be much longer.